# send the user input to url and fetch the result and display it in the program in cocoa objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, url

I am writing a program that would allow for online currency exchange on a MAC, I wanted to use the information on www.xe.com .
 I was wondering if 
A) if it would be possible for me to do that. and if yes the 
B) if it would be possible for the program to send the user input to the website and then fetch the result and display it in the program?

http://www.xe.com/ucc/convert.cgi?Amount=1&From=EUR&To=USD

Answer (score 1):

To fetch a URL in Cocoa, there are a number of ways, but the "best" one is to use `NSURLConnection` — see [its docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [the guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) for more information.

Also note that xe.com may have a usage policy! Don't abuse it!